# How to reload keynotes using pyRevit

Tags: python, revit-api, revit, pyrevit

I am attempting to modify the extremely helpful open keynotes button script to create a 'reload keynotes' button.

Currently i am trying to use the Reload Method of the KeyBasedTreeEntryTable class.

```
kt = DB.KeynoteTable.GetKeynoteTable(revit.doc)
kt_ref = kt.GetExternalFileReference()
path = DB.ModelPathUtils.ConvertModelPathToUserVisiblePath(
    kt_ref.GetAbsolutePath()
    )

reloader = DB.KeyBasedTreeEntryTable.Reload()



if not path:
    forms.alert('No keynote file is assigned.')
else:
    reloader
```

This is the error message that i am receiving.

> TypeError: Reload() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

[image: Error Message Image]

I am stuck here and appreciate any help.

Comment: I am not sure what arguments the Reload method is looking for...

Comment: You will find some hints about the parameter [in this doc](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/a91169d7-4f71-c027-3a24-1d90473e7071.htm#parameters), but `Reload` is not a static method, you cannot call it directly from the class. the first parameter (implicit) should refer to the instance of the class `KeyBasedTreeEntryTable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Revit API to reload the keynotes, the method `KeyBasedTreeEntryTable.Reload` just needs a parameter to store warnings thrown during operation, this parameter can be `None` to make it easy.

Also `KeyBasedTreeEntryTable` should be an instance, the reload method is not static.

The cool thing is that you don't need to find any `KeyBasedTreeEntryTable` instance, because the [`KeynoteTable`](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018/e0fd9115-a579-bab4-31ad-542e897edc13.htm) class inherits from `KeyBasedTreeEntryTable`, so the `Reload` method is already available with the `kt` instance in your script.

(This operation needs a transaction context too, like in the following examples)

## Simple way

```
kt = DB.KeynoteTable.GetKeynoteTable(revit.doc)

t = DB.Transaction(revit.doc)
t.Start('Keynote Reload')
try:
    result = kt.Reload(None)
    t.Commit()

except:
    t.RollBack()

forms.alert('Keynote Reloading : {}'.format(result))
# result can be 'Success', 'ResourceAlreadyCurrent' or 'Failure'
```

## Complete way

```
kt = DB.KeynoteTable.GetKeynoteTable(revit.doc)

# create results object
res = DB.KeyBasedTreeEntriesLoadResults() 

t = DB.Transaction(revit.doc)
t.Start('Keynote Reload')
try:
    result = kt.Reload(res) # pass results object
    t.Commit()

except:
    t.RollBack()

# read results
failures = res.GetFailureMessages()
syntax_err =  res.GetFileSyntaxErrors()
entries_err = res.GetKeyBasedTreeEntryErrors()
# res.GetFileReadErrors() returns files errors, should be already in failures Messages

warnings = ''
warnings += '\n'.join([message.GetDescriptionText() for message in failures])

if syntax_err:
    warnings += '\n\nSyntax errors in the files :\n'
    warnings += '\n'.join(syntax_err)

if entries_err:
    warnings += '\nEntries with error :\n'
    warnings += '\n'.join([key.GetEntry().Key for key in entries_err])

forms.alert('Keynote Reloading : {}\n{}'.format(result, warnings))
```